# Forma correcta de "nisiquiera"

Tags: modismos, ortografía

#### Español

Al escribir siempre he tenido la duda de cuál es la manera apropiada del término o frase.

¿Cuál de estas es correcta?

- ni si quiera
- ni siquiera
- nisiquiera

---

#### English

When writing I've always worred about which is the appropriate way for this term or phrase.

Which one of the following is correct?

- ni si quiera
- ni siquiera
- nisiquiera

Comment: [I've always worried about the right way to write this term.] O sea, la manera correcta de escribirlo.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

La forma correcta es **ni siquiera** según Word Reference. Aquí está el porqué:

> [**siquiera**](http://www.wordreference.com/definicion/siquiera)
>
> 1. conj. ad. Bien que,aunque:
>        sé valiente,siquiera sea por una vez.
>        ♦ A veces se omite el verbo ser: deberías llamarlo,siquiera por gratitud.
> 2. adv. c. y m. Por lo menos,al menos. Se usa en contextos afirmativos:
>        permíteme siquiera que te lleve una bolsa.
> 3. Ni tan solo. Se usa en contextos negativos,para intensificarlos:
>        no quiso siquiera mirarme a la cara.
> 4. **ni siquiera** loc. adv. siquiera: no me pagó ni siquiera los atrasos.

> [**ni**](http://www.wordreference.com/definicion/ni)
>
> 1. conj. cop. Enlace coordinante con valor negativo,generalmente precedido de otra negación:
>        no quiero este ni aquel;
>        ni lo sé ni me interesa.
> 2. ni que Como si:
>        ¡ni que fuera tonto!
> 3. **ni (siquiera)** Expresión enfática para negar o para indicar el grado extremo de algo:
>        eso no te lo crees ni (siquiera) tú;
>        ¡no puedo verlo ni (siquiera) en pintura!

Como puedes ver, *ni* es para enfatizar lo que siquiera quiere decir (**ni tan solo**) es para intensificar un contexto negativo.

En fin, la pregunta era simple y me puse a divagar: se escribe ***Ni siquiera***.

Answer (score 2):

It's an adverbial locution:

> ni siquiera

* given that *siquiera* is a word

Answer (score 2):

Fundéu también escribió al respecto en [*siquiera, ni siquiera*](https://www.fundeu.es/consulta/siquiera-ni-siquiera-1243/), indicando que ***siquiera* es la forma correcta**:

> ¿Es correcto usar «siquiera» y «ni siquiera» de forma indistinta en oraciones negativas?
>
> *Siquiera* y *ni siquiera* (y *ni tan siquiera*) se emplean, en efecto, en las oraciones negativas con el mismo significado. Se trata de un uso que, por lo que hemos podido comprobar, se remonta, por lo menos, al siglo XVI.

Como puede verse en la definición del DLE, viene de la unión de la conjunción [*si*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=XmM8PPL%7CXmMshCc) y la conjugación del verbo *querer*:

> [**siquiera**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Y0gIPHg)
>   `De si y quiera, 3.ª pers. de sing. del pres. de subj. de querer.`
>
> 1. conj. conc. aunque. Hazme este favor, siquiera sea el último.
> 2. conj. distrib. ya. Siquiera venga, siquiera no venga.
> 3. adv. al menos (‖ aunque no sea otra cosa). Deme usted media paga siquiera.
> 4. adv. Tan solo. U. en contextos negativos o irreales. No tengo un euro siquiera.

La Nueva Gramática describe *si quiera* en su entrada [40.8f](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=pnDWvDhfPRWmViLv).

---

Dicho lo cual, veo en el CORPUS de la RAE bastantes entradas con *si quiera* (separado), que van menguando a medida que van pasando los siglos, pero siguen estando presentes incluso en 1955, en *La Hojarasca* de Gabriel García Márquez:

> Esa fue la primera vez que se vieron. Y fue también la última. Sin embargo, la vida del doctor se prolongó hasta esta madrugada porque El Cachorro intervino otra vez a su favor la noche en que le suplicaron que atendiera a los heridos y él *ni si quiera* abrió la puerta, y le gritaron esa terrible sentencia cuyo cumplimiento yo me encargaré ahora de impedir.